# Setting the tabIndex of the label generated by asp:listitem

Tags: asp.net

If I create a radio button group like this:

```
<asp:radiobuttonlist ID="rbListHeader" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Font-Size="12px" TabIndex="-1">
    <asp:listitem value="London" />
    <asp:listitem value="Newcastle" />
</asp:radiobuttonlist>
```

the html that is rendered includes a html label for each radio button. This label displays next to the radio buttons and displays either 'London' or 'Newcastle' on the screen. I have the TabIndex of the radiobuttonlist set to -1 but tabbing through the form the focus moves to the 'London' label. As this label seems to be auto generated, is there any way of setting the TabIndex of the generated labels to -1?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this via code using:

```
foreach (ListItem li in RadioButtonList1.Items)
    {       
        li.Attributes.Add("tabindex", "-1");
        counter -=1;
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Tabbing through the form the focus moves to the label 'London'. The radio buttons themselves don't get the focus anyway - setting the RadioButtonList's TabIndex to -1 seems to take care of that, but the first label definitely gets the focus.